# Does laplace transformation pairs carry over to inverse frequency functions.

Tags: laplace-transform

For example,
$$u(t) \leftrightarrow \frac{1}{s}$$
Does this carry over say
$$\frac{1}{u(t)} \leftrightarrow \frac{1}{\frac{1}{s}} = s$$